# install Dropbox on headless Ubuntu server

Tags: server, 18.04, browser, dropbox

I was reading the information on https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux (hope you'll see the text in your own language).
After installing Dropbox I had to copy a URL in an active browser.
How do I do that? My Ubuntu server (18.04) doesn't have a browser. After temporarily installing a tiny browser I am not able to uninstall it.

Hope anyone can help me.

Best regards,
Guido van Harten

Comment: Have you tried opening the URL on a different computer?

Comment: "My Ubuntu server (18.04) doesn't have a browser. " Sure but they meant you to do it on desktop connected to that server.